# How to install FFMpeg in WampServer 2.0 (Windows XP)

Tags: php, ffmpeg, video-streaming, wampserver

I need to install the ffmpeg PHP extension on my localhost so I can test few of my scripts but I am having troubles figuring out how to do that.

I have WampServer 2.0 with PHP 5.2.9-2, my OS is Windows XP. Please somebody give me step by step instructions.

I have found some Windows builds here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-php/files/

But I don't know which one to download and what to do with files.

EDITED:

What I have done so far:

1. Download ffmpeg_new
2. Copy php_ffmpeg.dll from the php5 folder to the C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.9-2\ext
3. Copy files from common to the windows/system32 folder
4. Add extension=php_ffmpeg.dll to php.ini file
5. Restarted all services (Apache, PHP...)

I am gettings an error after using this code:

```
            $extension = 'ffmpeg';
            $extension_soname = 'php_ffmpeg.dll';
            $extension_fullname = PHP_EXTENSION_DIR . "/" . $extension_soname;

            // load extension
            if(false === extension_loaded($extension)) {
                if (false === dl($extension_soname))
                    throw new Exception("Can't load extension $extension_fullname\n");
            }
```

The error:

```
Warning: dl() [function.dl]: Not supported in multithreaded Web servers - use extension=ffmpeg.dll in your php.ini in C:\wamp\www\hunnyhive\application\modules\default\controllers\MyAccountController.php on line 314
```

Plus I also get the exception from above.

Comment: While the comments below will help you with getting this working, I've found in the past that skipping the FFMPEG extension and simply calling the executable seems to be a much better solution.

Comment: Hi, please help in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608309/copy-step-written-on-stackoverflow-to-install-ffmpeg-on-wamp-not-working

Answer (score 5):

add this line to your php.ini file

```
[PHP_ffmpeg]
extension=php_ffmpeg.dll
```

Comment: You may also need to enable the extension: php_gd2.dll;

Comment: Hi, please help in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608309/copy-step-written-on-stackoverflow-to-install-ffmpeg-on-wamp-not-working

Answer (score 2):

http://sergey89.ru/files/ffmpeg-php-win32-all.zip

1. unpack ffmpeg-php-win32-all.zip
2. Copying php_ffmpeg.dll to the \wamp\php4\extension\ (for php5 it's
   \wamp\bin\php\ext)
3. Copying  avcodec.dll & avformat.dll and any other in package to the \windows\system32\
4. Editing \wamp\apache\apache2.xx\bin\php.ini - adding line extension=php_ffmpeg.dll
5. Restarting Apache.

Comment: Hi, please help in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608309/copy-step-written-on-stackoverflow-to-install-ffmpeg-on-wamp-not-working

Answer (score 1):

1. Download ffmpeg_new
2. Copy php_ffmpeg.dll from the php5 folder to the wamp/php/ext folder
3. Copy files from common to the windows/system32 folder

Comment: I have done that and also added extension=php_ffmpeg.dll to php.ini. But it still doesn't work, I'm going to edit my first post to contain error message.

Comment: Hi, please help in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608309/copy-step-written-on-stackoverflow-to-install-ffmpeg-on-wamp-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like the problem is with ffmpeg... the warning is about the use of the dl function.  Multi-threaded PHP does not support dynamic loading of any PHP extension, so you'll need to make sure the .dll file for it is placed wherever the rest of your php modules live.

What you really need to figure out is why the extension doesn't load despite the fact you've got the "extension=php_ffmpeg.dll" directive in your php.ini.  Usually you can see any startup errors in your apache error log (such as PHP saying it can't load a library).  Also, have you taken a look at a phpinfo() and verified ffmpeg isn't present (shouldn't be since the extension_loaded returns false), but perhaps it's there under a different name (you could also use get_loaded_extensions() I suppose).

Comment: I have checked the phpinfo() and the ffmpeg isn't there, so it's not loaded even though the dll file is in correct folder and it is enabled in php.ini. There is nothing in Apache error logs related to this problem but PHP error logs are full of the error message from my first post.

Comment: I have a feeling the problem is with the dll file, maybe it's compiled for older version of PHP? But I haven't found any other ffmpeg Windows builds on the Internet.

Comment: Yeah, I've personally never installed FFMPEG on anything but Ubuntu boxes... if I had a windows box to test on I'd give it a whack, but I dunno what else to tell you other than try to build it yourself :)

Comment: Hi, please help in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608309/copy-step-written-on-stackoverflow-to-install-ffmpeg-on-wamp-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Editing `\wamp\apache\apache2.xx\bin\php.ini` - adding line `extension=php_ffmpeg.dll`

INSTEAD OF

Editing `\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.9\php.ini` - adding line `extension=php_ffmpeg.dll`

Comment: Hi, please help in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608309/copy-step-written-on-stackoverflow-to-install-ffmpeg-on-wamp-not-working

Answer (score 1):

```
; Whether or not to enable the dl() function.  The dl() function does NOT work
; properly in multithreaded servers, such as IIS or Zeus, and is automatically
; disabled on them.
; http://php.net/enable-dl
enable_dl = Off
```

These are the lines in `php.ini`. Make sure that `enable_dl` is turned off. After that you will not get error.

Comment: Hi, please help in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608309/copy-step-written-on-stackoverflow-to-install-ffmpeg-on-wamp-not-working

Answer (score 0):

MirKo is correct but i'll like to add that

after

1. Download compiled dlls from here: http://sergey89.ru/files/ffmpeg-php-win32-all.zip
2. Extract and put php_ffmpeg.dll to you php ext folder
3. Put the rest of dlls to you windows/system32 folder
4. Restart apache and run phpinfo() - you should see the ffmpeg extension (btw you have to check php not apache error log if you are looking for errors wamp->php->php error log)

there is another step

6. Open php.ini file and find 
                              **;   extension=msql.dll**
   add after it
                              extension=php_ffmpeg.dll

Comment: Hi, please help in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608309/copy-step-written-on-stackoverflow-to-install-ffmpeg-on-wamp-not-working