# How to read information from .3gp and .mp4 using ffmpeg-php?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, wamp, mp4

I have a bit of a problem with ffmpeg-php. I'm trying to get some information from video files  and it works pretty fine with file formats like .avi, .mpg or .flv  but when I try to use .3gp or .mp4 in:

```
$movie = new ffmpeg_movie('path/to/file/test.3gp');
```

I get error like this :

```
ffmpeg_movie::__construct() []: ISO: File Type Major Brand: 3gp5
```

or

```
ffmpeg_movie::__construct() []: ISO: File Type Major Brand: mp42
```

I installed ffmpeg-php on WAMP using instructions found here: 
[How to install FFMpeg in WampServer 2.0 (Windows XP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172916/how-to-install-ffmpeg-in-wampserver-2-0-windows-xp)

I need those information to send them to ffmpeg using exec(). Anyone could help me with this?

Comment: Um... Are you sure these are errors and not the regular output of the program? Is nothing else output?

Comment: Yup. Kohana crashes and shows those two errors when I try to use 3.gp or .mp4. In any other case everything works fine. 

On ffmpeg-php website I've seen that maybe it happens so because ffmpeg have to be complied with zlib library. But if that is the case then I don't know how to do it :(

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a pure php approach using [PHP media reader](https://code.google.com/p/php-reader/)

Answer (score 0):

While installing ffmpeg plugin on server, Mostly we will be having "ffprobe" library with it. By using ffprobe, we can get details/metadata about videos.

```
$ffprobe_path="ffprobe"; //path to installation of ffprobe
$video_file="/home/testsite/public_html/videos/mytest_video.mp4"; //path to the specific video file

$ffprobe_cmd=$ffprobe_path." -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams ".$video_file;  
$outputprobe = shell_exec($ffprobe_cmd);  
$result_video_meta = json_decode($outputprobe);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result_video_meta);
echo "</pre>";
```