# Does PHP have an integrated function to read metadata from an mp4 file?

Tags: php, mp4

I want to know if PHP has a function to read metadata from an mp4 video-audio file. I've found some external classes that do that, but first of use them I would want to know if are necessary or PHP already have some method for do that.

Classes that I've found are **php-mp4info** and **getID3()**, which of them is better?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816684/how-to-read-information-from-3gp-and-mp4-using-ffmpeg-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best tool I have used is: https://code.google.com/p/php-reader/ have a look...also supports other forms of media.

**Edit:** PHP-Reader seems to be no longer maintained (project has not been updated since 2012...). You should use `getID3()` now.

Answer (score 3):

I've used http://getid3.sourceforge.net/ before for something similar, worked pretty well as far as I remember.

Comment: Either. Down to preference really