# PHP - Get some metadata of any type of file

Tags: php, python, file-upload, metadata, media

I am trying to get some **metadata** on **upload of images/videos**.
The goal is to make the upload of a large amount of files fast by setting their `$description` automatically by metadata.
I'd ideally use *Title* and *Object* (as litteraly translated).

`exif_read_data()` only accepts *JPEG*/*TIFF*, I'd use the `xattr_get()` which seems to be the best I could use but I don't find how to use it (maybe misunderstood something).
In my older researches I read I could **get metadata with Python** but it means I need to learn a bit of Python and how to use some in PHP.

I am not against learning Python but I heard (without examples, sadly) that I could do that with PHP.

- Is there a "universal" method in PHP to get metadata ?
- Or will I need to use one method by file type ?
- Or a maintained library ?
- If Python, how to proceed ?

Comment: Have you tried [this library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-reader/) ? Found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173471/does-php-have-an-integrated-function-to-read-metadata-from-an-mp4-file)

Comment: I haven't tried. I think I'll use it and use other functions for image files. The thing is I haven't installed a library/extension successfully yet, I've to work on it :) thanks again !

Comment: I'll try it today and use it. But it seems handle many extensions! Perhaps it handle images. If it does the job, I'll post it as answer.

Comment: It handles videos & music formats. For images, I will need to use something else.