# How to get m4a audio file length in PHP

Tags: php, audio, mp3, m4a

I have a php generated page that lists a few hundred m4a audio files with the audio controls.

If I use
<audio preload="metadata"
it doesn't load all the files due to timeouts getting the meta data from all the audio files.

If I use
<audio preload="none"
it loads fine and when I click play it shows the length (duration) of the m4a file I clicked play on no problem.

Is there a way to read the duration of the m4a file in PHP so I can display that?  I can get the duration of an mp3 in php but can't find anywhere how to get the duration of an m4a audio file in PHP

Comment: Which length do you mean? The duration of the sound, or the size of the file in bytes?
Also if you generate a list so huge that metadata cannot be fetched for all the files, I suggest that you use paging or dynamically load files on scrolling.

Comment: Looking for the duration of the songs. I will look into dynamically loading on scrolling but that is new for me.   Is there a wya though in PHP to read the song length of an M4A file to store it in a database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does PHP have an integrated function to read metadata from an mp4 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173471/does-php-have-an-integrated-function-to-read-metadata-from-an-mp4-file)