# install ffmpeg in wamp 2.0 php

Tags: php

the same problem i am also getting, i get the dll file from http://raghuram2404.blogspot.in/2012/06/install-ffmpeg-in-wamp-server-20.html and copy that in system32

as per instruction  given.
I restart the wamp  and run phpinfo();

but not getting the ffmpeg  in list

or is there other way to generate thumbnail from video upload

Comment: are you adding this extension=php_ffmpeg.dll in your php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Are you extracted and put php_ffmpeg.dll to your php ext folder?

Try to read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172916/how-to-install-ffmpeg-in-wampserver-2-0-windows-xp)